# Changing the style of an element after animation has been completed in react-spring

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

I have a very basic animation using react-spring. The goal is to animate the height of an element, and then after the animation has been completed, set the height of that element to "auto".

Here's what I'm trying:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accordionBodyRef.current) return;
    const accordionBodyDiv = accordionBodyRef.current;
    const height = `${accordionBodyDiv.scrollHeight}px`;
    if (isOpen) {
      bodySpringApi.start({
        to: { height },
        onRest: () => {
          accordionBodyDiv.setAttribute("style", "height: auto;");
          accordionBodyDiv.style.height = "auto";
        },
      });
    } else {
      bodySpringApi.start({
        from: {
          height,
        },
        to: {
          height: "0px",
        },
      });
    }
  }, [isOpen, bodySpringApi]);
```

I'm trying to manually set the style of the div using the ref in the "onRest" method of the spring api, but it just doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox example?

Comment: [Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sun-3tkll?file=/src/Accordion.js) @Josh

I was able to temporarily solve the problem by adding an extra piece of state, updating it in the onRest, and then setting the height: auto; in a separate useEffect. I'd still like to know how to do it in a better way though.